# Why is it a good idea for a server to create threads to handle clients’ requests?

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, client-server

Why is it a good idea for a server to create threads to handle clients’
requests?

Comment: So the entire server doesn't grind to a halt to deal with 1 request. Do you understand multithreading in general?

Comment: @carcigenicate what i understand is : In my opinion it is a good idea for a server to create threads for clients requests in order to handle multiple clients simutaneously whilst avoiding syncronization problems, 
as a lock can be put on the critical section of each thread, thus avoiding another thread to enter a critical section at the same time.

Comment: You seem to understand the advantage. I don't understand what you're asking then, as you appear to have just answered your own question.

Comment: is your question regarding `threading` vs `multiprocessing` in python and the global interpreter lock?

Answer (score 1):

This is because each request can take different time to fulfill, and at may involve sleeps, waits and the like.

So having threads dealing with requests will exploit the CPU much better than doing them sequentially. When one thread handling a requests that waits or sleeps, another thread will take its place and work on its request.

Answer (score 1):

Simply answer: because it helps you making more money; as it allows for better utilization of the server hardware.

The underlying reason is: when processing the request from one user, there are always situations where you simply have to wait. So why not process the request from user B; while you are waiting that the data received from user A is written to the database for example?!

Beyond that, threads are very "natural" model to design (and implement) the fact that your server is serving **many different** clients at the same point in time.